# How do I connect machines in Haskell with bidirectional relationships?

Tags: haskell

I am using the [Machines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/machines) library to model a turn based game.

I don't know how to connect the player and gamestage machines such that

1. When an Active player "Acts" the game is progressed to the next stage.
2. When the game stage progresses the status of the player is reset to `NotActedThisTurn`.

Here is what I have so far.

First lets define the stages of our game.

```
import Data.Machine

data Stage = One | Two deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

Which are progressed if all players have acted during the given stage.

```
data TurnStatus = AllPlayersActed | NotAllPlayersActed deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
```

Then we need a our game stage Mealy machine. We express the fact that a game stage cannot progress unless all players have acted in the given stage.

```
newHand :: Mealy TurnStatus Stage
newHand = Mealy toOne

toOne :: TurnStatus -> (Stage, Mealy TurnStatus Stage)
toOne AllPlayersActed = (One, Mealy toTwo)
toOne NotAllPlayersActed = (One, Mealy toOne)

toTwo :: TurnStatus -> (Stage, Mealy TurnStatus Stage)
toTwo AllPlayersActed = (Two, Mealy toOne)
toTwo NotAllPlayersActed = (One, Mealy toTwo)

stageMachine :: Monad m => MachineT m (Is TurnStatus) Stage
stageMachine = auto newHand
```

And the turn status Mealy to keep track of whether all players have acted this turn.

```
initTurnStatus :: Mealy Player TurnStatus
initTurnStatus = Mealy nextTurnStatus

nextTurnStatus :: Player -> (TurnStatus, Mealy Player TurnStatus)
nextTurnStatus _ = (NotAllPlayersActed, Mealy nextTurnStatus)

turnStatusMachine :: Monad m => MachineT m (Is Player) TurnStatus
turnStatusMachine = auto initTurnStatus
```

Then we need out Player and Action types and mealy machine.

```
data Action = Activate | Deactivate | Act deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data HasActed = ActedThisTurn | NotActedThisTurn deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data PlayerStatus = Active HasActed | Inactive deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

data Player = Player String PlayerStatus deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

```
initPlayer :: String -> Player
initPlayer n = Player n (Active NotActedThisTurn)

playerMealy :: Player -> Action -> (Either String Action, Player)
playerMealy (Player name Inactive) Activate =
    (Right Activate, Player name $ Active NotActedThisTurn)
playerMealy (Player name (Active _)) Activate = 
    (Left "couldnt activate as already active", Player name $ Active NotActedThisTurn)

playerMealy (Player name (Active _)) Deactivate = 
    (Right Deactivate, Player name Inactive)
playerMealy (Player name Inactive) Deactivate = 
    (Left "couldnt deactivate as already inactive", Player name Inactive)

playerMealy (Player name Inactive) Act = 
    (Left "couldnt act since inactive", Player name Inactive)
playerMealy (Player name (Active ActedThisTurn)) Act = 
    (Left "already acted this turn", Player name Inactive)
playerMealy (Player name (Active _)) Act = 
    (Right Act, Player name $ Active ActedThisTurn)

playerMealy' :: String -> Mealy Action (Either String Action)
playerMealy' name = unfoldMealy playerMealy $ initPlayer name

playerMachine :: Monad m => String -> MachineT m (Is Action) (Either String Action)
playerMachine = auto . playerMealy'

runPlayerMachine :: Monad m => String -> MachineT m (Is Action) (Either String Action)
runPlayerMachine name = source [Activate, Act] ~> playerMachine name
```

Comment: one question per post please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It has one question now which is how to connect two machines.